# Mutating an array

Tags: javascript

I want to change only the first column in the firs row but it doesn't work.

**wanted output is [[1,0],[0,0]], but what I get is[[1,0],[1,0]]**

**I want to know why this happens and what is the solution if I want to make a change in a different index ?**

```
let matrix = [];
let row = [0, 0];
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  matrix.push(row);
}

matrix[0][0] = 1;

console.log(matrix);
```

Comment: `matrix.push(row);` This is adding the same object over and over. When you change it in 1 place you change it in all the places.

Comment: Solution is `matrix.push([...row]);`

Comment: There's only one "row" reference--if you change it it will change everywhere it's referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you are pushing the same object (`row`) into the `matrix` twice.
Make a copy of `row` for example with the spread operator, or `Array.slice()`:

```js
let matrix = [];
let row = [0, 0];
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  matrix.push([...row]);
}

matrix[0][0] = 1;

console.log(matrix);
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `row` which is pushed to the matrix array points to the same memory location. So any update on this variable will be reflected everywhere.
You need to create a new one every time you push it

```js
let matrix = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  let row = [0, 0];
  matrix.push(row);
}
matrix[0][0] = 1;
console.log(matrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either just push a new array:

```
matrix.push([0,0])
```

Or you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
matrix.push([...row])
```